# java.lang.Class and generics

Tags: java, gwt

On this  gwt javadoc page http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html  `java.lang.Class<?>` is passed as parameter  to the create function. How is this valid?.. I could understand something like `create(List<Class> classLiteral)`  or  `create(java.lang.Class classLiteral)` but how the way it is used there confuses me greatly. Clarifications are much appreciated

Comment: `classLiteral` in `create(List<Class> classLiteral)` doesn't quite make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.lang.Class<?>` is the full type declaration of the instance. It is equivalent to

```
import java.lang.Class;

...

static <T> T create(Class<?> classLiteral) ...
```

They are just being thorough in the javadoc. `java.lang.Class` is a java class that represents classes. You can read its javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

You can access the Class object of a class with

```
YourClass.class // where class is a reserved java keyword will return an instance of type Class<YourClass>
```

If you have an instance

```
YourClass yourInstance = ...
yourInstance.getClass(); // will return an instance of type Class<YourClass>
```

If `<?>` is confusing you, it's known as a wildcard. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: Well yeah i know what a wildcard is ( guess not hehe). I have used it in other forms to like ? extends ClassY. But here it is used with a class that is declared as Class not declared as Class<?> bu. I'm going to check your links now and see if i can get to the bottom of this

Comment: ok so my first oops is that Class really is declared as Class <?> ... more to come..

Comment: @Malka The class `Class` is a generic class. `public final Class<T>`. You can see it in java source or in the javadoc. `<?>` is not the same as `<T>`. `<?>` means it could be anything. `T`, previously, is just a placeholder for the actual specified type.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, the method calls for a class literal, not an instance of a class. This means you are passing an actual class to the method instead of an instance of a class.

An example of this is if you were to call:

create(MyClass.class);

Here, you're passing a Class object, but not an instance of MyClass. So, the create method is asking for a Class object, not an instance of whatever Class you pass into it.

If it were class(java.lang.Class classLiteral), then it would be calling for an instance of any object that extends class.

Comment: yes i understand it calls for a class literal what i do not understand is how is Class<?> correct?...Shouldn't simple Class be used in this situation and not Class<?>; like create(java.lang.Class classLiteral)

Comment: @Malka `<?>` is known as a wildcard.

Comment: I would have picked this answer too